Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with TMP FDE, passphrase?
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with TPM Full Disk Encryption, everything works fine. Only my swap space is too small to hibernate. How can I retrieve / add a passphrase to decrypt the data partition for resizing? I only have a recovery key, which is not accepted with the live boot.
With a normal boot, the disk is unlocked, so I hoped to just add a passphrase
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p4

Unfortunately this command will ask for an existing passphrase
I got the suggestion to retrieve de masterkey
sudo dmsetup table --showkeys ubuntu-data-<UUID>

The expected answer is something like
0 976773168 crypt aes-xts-plain64 0123456789abcdef... [other details]

With 0123456789abcdef... being the masterkey. I got something like
0 976773168 crypt aes-xts-plain64 :64:logon:cryptsetup:18ae10b4... [other details]

And 18ae10b4.. is not the masterkey.
The disk is unlocked during a normal boot, so I got suggestions to use the unmapped disk as (master) key-file
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p4 --key-file=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-data-<UUID>

sudo head -c 8192 /dev/mapper/ubuntu-data-<UUID> | sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p4 --key-file=-

sudo head -c 65536 /dev/mapper/ubuntu-data-<UUID> | sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p4 --key-file=-

sudo cryptsetup --master-key-file=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-data-<UUID> luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p4

Unfortunately, this does not work. The unlocked partition is too large for a keyfile and truncating it to 8k / 64 kb makes is smaller, but it is not recognized as a keyfile.
So I'm looking for better options.
